# Error when i install ssl cert on my server,, ERROR: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

**HTML:**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="farmapp.css"> 

</head>

<body onload="loadimg()">

    <div id="sitehead">
        
    <div class="leftsection" onclick="location.href = 'mainsite.html';">
            <div>
            <img class="left-sunriseIMG" src="thumbnails/sunrise.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
            <h1 class="sitetitle">FARM</h1>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="middlesection">
            <div>
        <!--
            <input class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search District">
            <label>Search using DISTRICT : </label>
        -->

        
            <button type="button" class="clearsearch" value="" onclick="location.href = 'mainsite.html';">x</button>
            </div>
            <div>
            <button type="submit" class="search-button" onclick="SearchWithDistrict()">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>     
    </div>

    <div id="deals-box">
        <div class="about" onclick="location.href = 'About.html';">About</div>
        <div class="contact" onclick="location.href = 'contact.html';">contact</div>
        <div class="post" onclick="location.href = 'FishImageUpload.html';">Post-AD</div>
        <div class="edit" onclick="location.href = 'edit.html';">Edit-AD</div>
    </div>

    <div id="cimages"></div>

    <div id="FullImageView">
        <img id="FullImage" />
        <button id="CloseButton" onclick="CloseFullView()">Close</button>
    </div>

    <div id="FullDetailsView">
        <div id="ViewDetails"></div>
        <button id="DetailsCloseButton" onclick="CloseDetailsView()">Cancel</button> 
    </div>
    

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**javascript:**

```js
function loadimg() {

    options = {
      method: 'POST',
    }
    
    fetch('https://apfarmsite.com:8000/FarmSite', options)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(cust_data => {  // Handle the response from the server
        console.log(cust_data);
      });
}
```

**app.js**

```js
app.post('/FarmSite', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
})
```

I am unable to connect to my API when I do post request. it gives me ssl error. This happens only when I use ssl cert on my server(HTTPS). IT is working when I use HTTP. I am using nginx. I have allowed full traffic in security groups for this ec2 instance. Do I have to adjust any SSL/TLS protocol settings?

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to various reasons. Try to update the browser if there needs to be as well as clear the cache of the browser. Sometimes the antivirus cause the problem. I had similar problem due to antivirus.Try to disable it.
Also I think for API call the method should be 'GET'.